# Change IMG src when hover a text menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Currently I am using the code below to change the image but what I needed to do is change the image the same time I hover at the title link of the image

```
onmouseover="this.src='Images/img.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Images/img2.png'"
```

For example
when someone hover to the title link e.g. 'Chicken Menu' the image below it will change from img.png to img2.png wherein img.png is a front page and img2.png is where my list of menu can be found

Comment: Any reason not to use `background-image` and `:hover`?

Comment: To answer this, we need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this using only CSS you can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) (+).

considering ur HTML as -

```
<div id="headingtext">HEADING</div>
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```

CSS can be -

```
#headingtext:hover + #imgDiv {
    background-image: url("https://images.blogthings.com/thesingleflowertest/flower-3.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:500px;
}

#imgDiv {
    background-image: url("https://images.blogthings.com/thesingleflowertest/flower-5.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:500px;
}
```

Fiddle Demo : 
http://jsfiddle.net/3z8CN/

Comment: I gave you +1 but please don't encourage inline styling ;)

Comment: :) Good eye. Although this is just a demo, I cleaned it.

Comment: Nice, I know it's just a demo but people here learn and some of them will probably be encouraged to use it if you show them ;)

Comment: Here is what I did
 a bit long to paste it here http://pastie.org/9069863 but it is not changing the img src

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<img src="http://www.blogwmp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/google-logo-100x100.png" alt="">

<script>
    $('a').hover(function(){
        $('img').attr("src", "http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/download/file.php?avatar=16617_1318156786.png");             
    }, function(){
        $('img').attr("src", "http://www.blogwmp.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/google-logo-100x100.png");             
    });
</script>
```

[**Here's the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLNmx/)

So with `.hover()` you change the attribute `src` of the image and you replace it by your other image. `.hover()` has parameter `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` so when the mouse leaves the link we put back the initial image.

Comment: I think this update of your code could be interesting http://jsfiddle.net/zLNmx/1/

Comment: In fact if the image is directly related to the link it could be useful but I don't think it's the case because if it is, in a lot of case it would be better to use CSS with background-image.

Comment: I agree with that, but in some case a `a` could contain a div tag or other

Answer (score 0):

check the fiddle...

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5Pss/2/)

you need to add the jquery

--HTML--

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class='my_span'>this is image</span>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class='my_span'>this is image</span>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

-- jquery --

```
$('span.my_span').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).next('img').attr("src","http://dummyimage.com/100x100/888888/000");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next('img').attr("src", "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff");             
    }
);
```